# Can I trust sprintf() to eliminate floating point imprecision?

Tags: c, printf, precision

I have the following C code to determine the decimal places of a double value. It is using the `sprintf()`'s `%f` for ending up with a string without floating point imprecision. Is there a risk that `sprintf()` is not eliminating the floating point imprecision correctly, or is that function safe to use?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_STRING 256

int getDecimalPlaces(double n)
{
    char string[MAX_STRING];
    int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 0;
    int i = sprintf(string, "%f", n);
    bool countZero = false;
    for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)
    {
        if (string[j] == '.')
            break;
        if (!countZero && string[j] != 48)
            countZero = true;
        if (countZero)
            numberOfDecimalPlaces++;
    }
    return numberOfDecimalPlaces;
}
```

I call the function for numbers to perform a mathematical operation with them (least common multiply). I need whole numbers for this operation so that I am searching for the number with the most decimal places. Then I am multiplying each number by 10 ^ (most decimal places). The numbers dealt with are user-entered and belong to a linear system of equations. In most cases, 2 decimal places are enough.

The numbers itself don't have to be *very* precise, but their decimal places *have* to match up with what a user entered.

Comment: “Floating point imprecision” is not what you think it is, and there is not enough information in this question to say whether the results will be what you want.

Comment: When I am calling the function with `1.4` I am expecting to get `1` returned. I don't want to have my program handle the number as `1.3999999999999...`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that 'eliminating the floating point imprecision' is actually possible, in the general case, without sacrificing accuracy:(

Comment: You are right, but `sprintf()` or `printf()` is so far I can tell returning the value I want to _see_ and not the internal representation. So I am wondering if I can trust that for determining the decimal places of a number.

Comment: FYI, your 1st `for` loop is unnecessary and should be removed. It is replicating what `strlen()` does, and besides is redundant since `sprintf()` returns the number the characters it writes to the string buffer.

Comment: The problem of accurately displaying a float with as few digits as possible is tricky. There are specialized algorithms that do it, look into what libfmt uses (though it's a c++ library).  It uses [dragonbox](https://github.com/jk-jeon/dragonbox/blob/master/other_files/Dragonbox.pdf) I think?

Comment: displaying a float is not the same as what the float actually is.

Comment: Whenever an operation with a floating-point result is performed, the result equals the real-number-arithmetic result rounded to a number representable in the floating-point format. Commonly, the rounding method is round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, but the C standard permits flexibility in this. Converting numerals in source code, like `3.14`, to floating-point is such an operation. Addition is such an operation. Multiplication is such an operation. Thus, the rounding in each and every operation adds some error, or, if you lucky, cancels some error…

Comment: … The import of this is that, by the time you have a result to give to `sprintf`, we do not know how much error is in it. Your question contains not a single word about the magnitudes of the numbers you will use nor the operations performed on them. So we have no information about how much error will be in the number, so we cannot say whether the result of the formatting by `sprintf` will be the result you want.

Comment: The C standard does provide a guarantee that the rounding performed by `sprintf` in formatting its `%f` output will be correctly rounded (presumably meaning round-to-nearest) as long as the number of digits requested at most `DECIMAL_DIG`, which is at least 10.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I added my specific use case to the question. I hope I could make it clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Luqus: The text is vague, does not state any bound on the magnitudes involved, and does not show any example. The fact the numbers “belong to a linear system of equations” suggests that multiple operations will be performed on them. As described above, each operation can compound the error. When successive calculations are performed, it is possible for errors to grow to infinity or to form NaNs. You must provide full information.

Comment: The full algorithm is over 200 lines long. But what I am essentially doing with that function above is determining the _most_ decimal places occurring in a (large) vector. Sizes can range from 1x2 to infinity. Note that users should be able to enter their own values, and the use case for my entire program is solving a linear system of equations. If you rounded a number to 2 decimal places in a calculation the tiny imprecision is not going to matter, for me neither. But there is a massive problem when my program thinks 1.4 has more than 1 decimal place. I am sorry if my English is not the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function only produces 6 decimals for any finite number, so it cannot return a number of decimals greater than `6` and the number of decimals returned can be much smaller than anticipated: if the value is not an integer but close enough, the function will return `0`, eg: `getDecimalPlaces(1.0000004)` or `getDecimalPlaces(1.9999996)`.

`%f` formats the number with a fixed number of decimals, which you can specify with a *precision* field, such as `%.10f`. It defaults to `6`.

If you want to determine the number of decimals needed to represent the value `n` unambiguously, you should use `%320.18g` and handle the exponent part that may be produced for values between `-1` and `1`.

Note, however, that the `double` type uses a binary representation for floating point values internally. Unless the value is an exact multiple of a negative power of 2, the representation is an approximation of its decimal representation.

For example `1.5` is represented exactly, without approximation, but `0.1` is not, just like 1/3 cannot be represented exactly using a decimal representation.

The internal representation of `0.1` is approximate, but depending on the implementation of `sprintf()`, converting this approximate value to decimal can produce `0.1000000000000000000013552527156068805425093160010874271392822265625` or just `0.1`, as both will convert back to the same value.

`sprintf` is not safe to use as coded in your function: for a very large number, greater than 1e250, `snprintf` will produce more than 256 characters and write beyond the end of the array. It is much safer to use `snprinf`.

If your goal is to convert the value in decimal form with at most 6 decimals and no exponent, you can change you can use this modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int convertValue(char *dest, size_t size, double d, int maxplaces) {
    int len = snprintf(dest, "%.*f", maxplaces, d);

    while (n > 0 && string[len - 1] == '0')
        string[--len] = '\0';
    if (len > 0 && string[len - 1] == '.')
        string[--len] = '\0';
    return len;
}
```

**EDIT:** for your purpose, you want to convert the numbers to integers. Make sure you use `round(d * power_of_10)` to ensure proper conversion.  Without the `round()`, you might get incorrect conversions, such as `0.7 * 10` converting to `6` instead of `7`.

Comment: Sorry if I may be misunderstanding this, but when I specify any double value, the function _has_ returned the correct number in all cases. `double d = 3.451; int k = getDecimalPlaces(d); printf("%d\n", k);` `--> 3`

Comment: @Luqus: you are correct, but the function can return `0` for a value that is not a whole number, for example `0.0000001`.

Comment: Re “Your function should return `6` for any finite number”: `getDecimalPlaces(3.5))` returns 1.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: you are correct, I amended the answer.

Comment: @chqrlie I know what you mean. It isn't a perfect function for too small numbers and I could edit this, but it isn't necessary for my use case.